# React Native don't allow empty text inputs on submit

Tags: react-native

I want a textinput for numbers where the text is set to 0 if it's empty on submit.
It is easy to achieve if you do it onChangeText

```
onChangeText={text => text || 0}
```

But then it comes up immediately, and if you type the zero will stay put before the new text. I would like to change the value from onEndEditing or onBlur, but I don't know how to access the textfield from there, or it could be something like

```
onEndEditing={text => value(text || 0)}
```

Comment: I've made a hacky solution by using onChangeText={text => +text || 0}, which adds up the numbers rather then concatenating them.